# Solr sort term based on two fields with an AND

Tags: solr

I am running a solr query against a large group of cats. The cats have four relevant attributes:

```
Eye color (string)
Stray (1 yes/0 no)
Relevancy (integer 1-99)
Age(integer representing milliseconds).
```

I want my sort results to be the following:

1. Cats with green eyes AND a stray
2. Relevancy
3. Age

So my results will look like this:

```
Green, 1, 50, 300000
Green, 1, 25, 500000
Green, 1, 25, 100000
Blue,  1, 99, 500000
Green, 0, 98, 500000
Red,   1, 98, 400000
Green, 0, 98, 399999
```

I don't care the color of the eyes or stray status, unless it is both green eyes and a stray.

This sort parameter works but is missing the "stray" flag:

```
if(exists(query({!v=eyes:"Green"})),1,0)+desc,
relevancy+desc,
age+desc
```

This sort parameter doesn't work and throws an error:

```
if((exists(query({!v=eyes:"Green"}))) AND 
(exists(query({!v=stray:1}))),1,0)+desc,
relevancy+desc,
age+desc
```

I'm really lost here, not sure if I am using sort incorrectly, or if I am misunderstanding syntax.

Error Message: `Can't determine a Sort Order (asc or desc) in sort spec 'if((exists(query({!v=eyes:"Green"})) AND exists(query({!v=stray:1}))),1,0) desc,relevancy desc,age desc'`

Comment: Please add the error snippet as well.

Comment: `{!v=eyes:"Green" AND stray:1}` ? It's usually more readable to use parameter dereferencing in these cases: `... query($qq) ...&qq=eyes:Green AND stray:1`

Comment: Added error message @San

Comment: Got the same error message for `{!v=eyes:"Green" AND stray:1}`, trying the second suggestion with parameter dereferencing right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for my case, it was a nest if that was needed:

`if(exists(query({!v=eyes:"Green"})),if(exists(query({!v=stray:1})),1,0),0)+desc,`

I might be using an out of date version of solr, that's probably why @MatsLindh answer did not work for me